# How to remove "" from json string

Tags: php, json, laravel

I want to remove double quotes("") from outside of the string.

I have below string.

```
$p = "{\"match\":\"https:\/\/mong.com\/sddaad\",\"type\":\"exact\",\"activated\":\"True\"}"
```

I'd like the result to be like this:

```
$p = {\"match\":\"https:\/\/mong.com\/sddaad\",\"type\":\"exact\",\"activated\":\"True\"}
```

**I think it is a good question to show powerful code, I don't understand why people vote against me and close my question. The closer must don't know the best answer!!!**

Comment: Because i want to save json data in my database in this format.

Comment: json_decode it:`$p = json_decode("{\"match\":\"https:\/\/mong.com\/sddaad\",\"type\":\"exact\",\"activated\":\"True\"}")`

Comment: **Not working**

Comment: Check the answer, you will see more details

Comment: you can use trim method to remove "".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this,
You can json_decode and then encode using `JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES`

```
$p = "{\"match\":\"https:\/\/mong.com\/sddaad\",\"type\":\"exact\",\"activated\":\"True\"}";
echo json_encode(json_decode($p),JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/DG6EE)

You can save output to a database without any problem and you can read the same using json_decode.

**Output**

```
{"match":"https://mong.com/sddaad","type":"exact","activated":"True"}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you are confused. You want to remove the double quotes outside of a string but actually that's just the definition of string.

If you simple `echo` your value you will see that the double quotes that you want to remove are not there anyway.

`Json` is handled as a string normally so it is expected to be enclosed in quotes. What matters is the format of your json in order to use it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what dou you want to achieve but you may want to look at `trim` method

```
$string = "sample text"

trim($string, '"')
```

`trim` deletes specified character both end and start of the string. If there is no expression specified, it removes whitespaces

Comment: would not do anything in your example, the `"` are string delimiters

Comment: @N69S I know right ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use PHP function addslashes() to make it work.

```
<?php 
$json_array = array(
'title' => 'I love Dexter series this is a test\'s with "special" characters'
);

echo $json_decode =addslashes(json_encode($json_array));

?>
```

Output : {\"title\":\"I love Dexter series this is a test\'s with \\"special\\" characters\"}

Comment: he wants to remove the `"` outside of `{..}` wich are string delimiters, trim will not do that.

Comment: it's not working

Comment: please check the updated answer

Answer (score -1):

$p= preg_replace('/"([a-zA-Z]+[a-zA-Z0-9_]*)":/','$1:',$p);

Answer (score -1):

What you need to do to save it in a json field in laravel, is taking your string and decode it into an array then set your attribute value to that array.

```php
$p = "{\"match\":\"https:\/\/mong.com\/sddaad\",\"type\":\"exact\",\"activated\":\"True\"}"
$value = json_decode($p, true); //second parameter to get the result as an associative array
$user->properties = $value;
$user->save();
```

dont forget to set the cast of that attribute in your model class

```php
class User extends Model
{
    protected $casts = [
        'properties' => 'array'
    ];
```